# Encoding string is differing with asp.net server.URL encoding when using '?' in the string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

When I am using in aps.net to encode the string, the function I'm using is `Server.UrlEncode(GAE?)`, which returns the string `GAE%3f`.

When I am using javascript function to encode `encodeURIComponent(GAE?)` it is returning `GAE%3F`.

But when i validate the string it will never match since my validation failing.
Requirement is there any way to encoded  `encodeURIComponent(GAE?)` as `GAE%3f` as it is my requirement.

Other wise please let me know `Server.UrlEncode` code encoding it as capital 'F' this letter making difference. 
Note:Any way to get 'F' in small case when I use `encodeURIComponent(GAE?)`, The question mark (`?`) encoded as `%3F` but it should be `%3f`

Comment: Can you decode them back to it's original and then compare? Also, are you comparing the results in Javascript or in c#? do you care about letter case of the other parts of the encoded string? (should `gae%3f` be considered different then `GaE%3F`)?

Comment: Comparing in javascript not in C#

Answer (score 0):

Please try `Uri.EscapeDataString("?")`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to decode then do the comparison.

But if you have to do the comparison before that for any reason, this is the code you can use to change the encoded "special characters" to lower/upper:

```
string FixEncode(string val) {
    var result = new StringBuilder(val);
    int searchIndex = val.IndexOf('%');

    while (searchIndex >= 0)
    {
        result[searchIndex + 1] = char.ToUpper(result[searchIndex + 1]);
        result[searchIndex + 2] = char.ToUpper(result[searchIndex + 2]);
        searchIndex = val.IndexOf('%', searchIndex + 2);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

You can run this function on both strings and then compare:

```
if (FixEncode(str1) == FixEncode(str2)) { /*...*/ }
```